# VBS Msgbox(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")) show error

Tags: vbscript

Please help. My code just simple but show error as in the picture.

```
Msgbox DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no DateTime object in VBScript, just plain Date variables and functions:

```
>> d = Date()
>> n = Now()
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(d), d, TypeName(n), n
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(Month(n)), Month(n)
>> s = FormatDateTime(n)
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(s), s
>>
Date 21.06.2017 Date 21.06.2017 05:58:13
Integer 6
String 21.06.2017 05:58:13
```

You can use a .NET `System.Text.StringBuilder` to do more fancy formatting. (cf [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9641534/603855))